# Sort columns from most common to least common, ignoring duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a list over the most common langauges in the world, from the world table, by determining how many people speak them.

So far I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT language, TRUNCATE((country.population * countrylanguage.percentage / 100), 0) AS People
FROM countrylanguage, country
WHERE code = countrycode
ORDER BY People DESC
```

And it's almost giving me what I want, but the languages won't add up properly, for example English showing up multiple times for every time it's mentioned as a language. I know I've got it wrong somewhere, I just can't figure out where.

[image]

Edit: Saw pic was in Norwegian. Left column is Language, right is number of people who speak them.

Comment: Can you show us sample table data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably intend to do some sort of aggregation here.  I would guess that you should be aggregating the number of speakers over each language and then reporting this:

```
SELECT t1.language,
       TRUNCATE(SUM(t2.population * t1.percentage / 100), 0) AS people
FROM countrylanguage t1
INNER JOIN country t2
    ON t1.countrycode = t2.code
GROUP BY t1.language
ORDER BY people DESC
```

Note that I have replaced your implicit join with an explicit one which uses `INNER JOIN` along with an `ON` clause.  It is considered desirable by most to write a query with joins in this way, because it makes it easier to see what is happening.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for future reference, using joins. Also, SUM seemed to be what I was missing. I can't believe that slipped my mind. Thank you very much, for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `JOIN` and aggregation, with an aggregation function:

```
SELECT cl.language,
       TRUNCATE(SUM(c.population * cl.percentage) / 100), 0) AS People
FROM countrylanguage cl JOIN
     country c
     ON c.code = cl.countrycode
GROUP BY cl.language
ORDER BY People DESC;
```

The use of `TRUNCATE()` for this purpose seems odd.  You want to return `People` as an integer.  The more typical function is `FLOOR()`:

```
SELECT cl.language,
       FLOOR(SUM(c.population * cl.percentage) / 100) AS People
FROM countrylanguage cl JOIN
     country c
     ON c.code = cl.countrycode
GROUP BY cl.language
ORDER BY People DESC;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . I must have started before you posted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . To be honest, the post started with a diatribe about using `select distinct` with `sum()` . . . then I realized that the OP didn't have `sum()` in the `select`, that being the problem.  Usually, I do answer faster ;)